# ZF2 InputFilterManager and validator injection

Tags: php, validation, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

I have one thing I'm not sure how to solve in a good way: I'm trying to use ZF2 `InputFilterManager` for fetching my input-filters, which make use of some own validators.

I added the validators to service manager config, so they can be fetched by InputFilterManager and get injected by keyword reference inside the InputFilter definition. that works fine, as far as validators doesn't need anyting to get injected or some objects, that are available from the ServiceLocator.

But one validator needs to get an array injected to do an in_array check inside. It is *not* possible to inject that array inside the validator factory, because it depends on business logic that runs before InputFilter `isValid()` call happens.

Without using service manager I would inject that array with constructor of the validator and would initialize it after business logic was called. So the question is: If I remove injection by constructor to use `InputFilterManager` I would need to inject it later by using: `$inputFilter->get('element')->getValidatorChain()->plugin(Validator\ArrayCheck::class)->setPossibleValues($array)` - is this the way to go?

I quite like to have necessary dependencies getting injected into classes by using the constructor and it feels somehow dirty to rewrite validator to rely on a setter injection and add a check to verify the setter was used before running `isValid()` logic.

Some code to explain my concern:

```
return [
    'validators' => [
        'invokables' => [
            Validator\ArrayCheck::class => Validator\ArrayCheck::class
        ]
    ],
    'input_filters' => [
        'invokables' => [
            InputFilter\Foo::class => InputFilter\Foo::class,
        ],
    ],
];

final class Process extends InputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'foo',
                'required' => true,
                'allow_empty' => false,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => Validator\ArrayCheck::class]
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}

class ArrayCheck extends AbstractValidator
{
    /**
     * @param array $possibleValues
     * @param array|Traversable $options
     */
    public function __construct(array $possibleValues = [], $options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->possibleValues = $possibleValues;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $possibleValues
     */
    public function setPossibleValues(array $possibleValues)
    {
        $this->possibleValues = $possibleValues;
    }

    ...

}
```

Any opinions on that?

Comment: You write *It is not possible to inject that array inside the validator factory*, can you explain why? Where does this business logic come from or depend on? If this runs before `isValid` it should be fine to inject it, right?

Comment: It def runs before the `isValid` call happens. But as I inject the `InputFilter` by constructor into the class, where business logic is placed, the initialization of the `InputFilter` already happend before the business logic kicks in. So there is no possibility to inject that array by constructor, only by using a setter and call it by using this ugly `$inputFilter->get('element')->getValidatorChain()->plugin(Validator\ArrayCheck::class)->setPossibleValues($array)` call. It's more a matter of bad design, as I def like to have dependencies getting injected by constructor.

Comment: business logic happpens inside service and it is an array coming from a db query (depending on a value/id that is coming into service from a controller route param, so this value is not part of the data, that gets validated). I could inject the entitymanager to do query stuff inside my validator, but I still  miss the value/id coming from the controller (and would need to inject that by setter, and this would make it not really a better design)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the `Callback` filter and `Callback` validator classes.

A callback filter runs a function or a class method when filtering your value. You can read on the `Callback` filter class [here in the ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html#callback). You can find the class [here on GitHUB](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-filter/blob/master/src/Callback.php).

A callback validator runs a function or a class method when validating your value. You can read on the `Callback` validator class [here in the ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.callback.html). You can find the class [here on GitHUB](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/Callback.php).

They both use [the PHP function `call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)  internally.

So let's say you need to filter using your `dependent business logic` in a class `My\Filter\Dependency` and your method is called `filterLogic` and/or you need to validate using your `dependent business logic` in a class `My\Validator\Dependency` and your method is called `validateLogic`. You do that like this:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'foo',
        'required' => true,
        'allow_empty' => false,
        `filters` => [
            [
                'name' => \Zend\Filter\Callback::class
                'callback' => [
                    'My\Filter\Dependency::filterLogic'
                ],
                'options'  => [
                    'argument1' => 'param1', //optional
                    'argument2' => 'param2'  //optional
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'validators' => [
            [
                'name' => \Zend\Validator\Callback::class
                'callback' => [
                    'My\Validator\Dependency::validateLogic'
                ],
                'options'  => [
                    'argument1' => 'param1', //optional
                    'argument2' => 'param2'  //optional
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Both the `Callback` classes will call `call_user_func_array` with your values for `callback` and `options` as arguments.

If you need the values from your input-filter in the callback functions then you will have to get them from your `InputFilter` instance manually (`$inputFilter->getRawValues();`) and pass them to the function as an argument.

If this is not solving your issue please try to explain better what you need. I can try to come up with something else :D

Comment: I don't get how this would help me with the problem of bad design decision by using setter injection. I try hard to inject dependencies by constructor into my validator classs. If I would initialize my InputFilter _after_ my business logic code, there is no problem. I inject needed array coming from business logic into the `InputFilter` and from there into the `validator` by using the `constructor`. By using `InputFilterManager` that's not possible anymore, because initialization of `InputFilter` (and `validator`) already happend before.